# How to resize the application in WPF depending on the tab size

Tags: wpf, resize

I designing an application using WPF that contain many tabs, some of the tab has some information and some has more information that take more space than the others, I don't want to create a static size for the application and leave a lot of white spaces where the tab hold less info, I want the application automatically change it original size depend on the selected tab, is it possible in WPF and if yes could you help me to show me how? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Stackoverflow is a question and answer site. You may have more luck if you show what you've already tried, identify a problem, and ask for specific help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for ideas!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking for the `SizeToContent` property on `Window` which automatically resizes the Window based on its contents. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @rshepp yes I want to automatically adjust the window size depend of it content, I will read about the SizeToContent and let you know if this will work for me